# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in using Default constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code and i receive this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Could anyone help me, please!!!

```
CREATE TABLE Company_costumers(
Nume VARCHAR(100) NULL,
Prenume VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
User_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AGE int NOT NULL CHECK(AGE>=18 AND AGE < = 110),

CREATE_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Comment: That looks like a Sql Server Create Table. Sysdate is the equivalent to Getdate() in Oracle. Also in Oracle varchar2 is more commonly use that varchar (they are synonims)

Comment: Datetime is not valid in Oracle

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like an Oracle `Create Table`

```
CREATE TABLE Company_costumers
  (
    Nume    VARCHAR2(100) NULL,
    Prenume VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    User_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AGE     INT NOT NULL CHECK(AGE>=18 AND AGE < = 110),
    CREATE_DATE DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL
  );
```

- Changed varchar to varchar2
- Datetime to Date
- Getdate() to Sysdate

Comment: ... and you are missing sysdate from the table definition (the default date value)   :-)